# unix sed command does not work

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to edit a file called BookDB.txt which contains

```
Boy:Man:67.00:15:28

Harry Potter - Order of Phoenix:J.K.Rowling:70.00:40:20
Harry Potter - Half Blood Prince:J.K.Rowling:40.00:50:20
```

this is my command

```
sed -i "s/""$title""/""$newtitle""/g" ./BookDB.txt
```

It works. 
But I want to make sure that it edits the exact string of $title, because if lets say it contains "a", then all the letter a in my file will be changed.
How do i use the `<\ \>` in this case ?

Comment: Why not `sed -i "s/$title/$newtitle/g" ./BookDB.txt`? Where `$title` and `$newtitle` are variables containing the term and replacement. Your quotes are a bit too numerous. It is unclear why you suggest boundary expressions, please add additional explanation.

Comment: My teacher told us that we had to always put quotes around variables. I know it looks really stupid but he says if the variable contains a space the whole program will screw up

Comment: He is right there, but the `"s/././g"` quotes count there and the `/../../` delimiters prevent any other interpretation of what the strings are. `:)`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple option you could try, since the title begins at the beginning of the line and is delimited by a colon, is this:

```
sed -i "s/^""$title:/""$newtitle"":/g" BookDB.txt
```

Note that `^` anchors the match to the beginning of the line, and `:` is in both the match and replacement section.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Thats a really smart way